# Minimum number of tiles that are needed.

Tags: combinatorics, tiling

This is a coloring proof problem from Arthur Engel: Consider an $m \times n$ rectangle, what is the minimum number of $1 \times 1$ tiles that are needed to be colored such that the remaining portion cannot be covered by L-Tetromino.

I tried to color rows alternatively as 'a' and 'b', but don't seem to be getting anywhere. Can anyone please help? (Please try to be explanative as I am not very good at coloring proofs.)

Comment: It seems that if you use three colors to color diagonals in rotation, you can get away with roughly $\frac 13$ of the area being covered by tiles.  No matter how the L-Tetromino is oriented, it has to hit $3$ diagonals.  However, I don't see how to prove that this is optimal.

Comment: Did you try reading the solution in the book? If yes, what did you not understand about it? $\quad$ FWIW the "color rows alternatively as a and b" is a great start to a solution. It guarantees that you can't have any L shape left.

Comment: @RobertShore I disagree.  L itself just hits just 2 \ (top left to bottom right) diagonals. Maybe you are counting \ and / diagonals as distinct? If so, that increases the number of tiles that you have to color.

Comment: @CalvinLin How can an L-tetromino (a line of $3$ adjacent to a line of $1$) fail to hit $3$ different diagonals?  The line of $3$ (in any orientation) has to hit $3$ separate diagonals.  Use the top-left-to-bottom right diagonals starting at a1, a4, a7, c8, f8.  That's $21$ squares.  How can you place the L-tetromino?  This proves you can always solve the problem with no more than $\left \lfloor \frac{mn}{3} \right \rfloor$ tiles.  But I still can't prove that's optimal.  Maybe by induction?

Comment: @CalvinLin I didn't understand the approach the author took after the coloring.

Comment: @PragyanSrivastava Please transcribe the problem correctly. Arthur Engel refers to " L-tromino", which are 3 equal squares. You wrote it is "L-Tetromino", which have 4 squares.  $\quad$ If you don't understand the approach the author took, then I recommend you ask a question to clarify the approach and ideas behind it.

Comment: @RobertShore Ah, apologies, I was looking at the source material, instead of what OP typed up. There was a difference as I just stated. $\quad$ For the L-tetromino, I agree that mn/3 seems like a reasonable guess.